# Using W3C PointerEvent API and be able to detect a double click?

Tags: javascript, double-click, pointer-events

Writing a rich web application I have the need to support all types of users, some are using a mouse, some are using a touch screen (e.g. on a mobile device). So the W3C PointerEvent API is exactly what I need to handle the user interactions. This works fine, except for one important case: double clicks.

There are a few things in the way:

- There is no (high level) event like "`pointerdblclick`", only the low level `pointerdown` and `pointerup` are available.
- To fix that and calculate the double click myself it is often recommended to use the property `detail` of the emitted event and check whether it has the value `2`. But this property is always `0` in my case.
- But even tracking this number myself will not work perfectly, as the OS (and possible setting by the user) is defining the maximum delay that is making two clicks to a double click.

So what can I do to react on a double click by mouse or a double tab by touch when all other user interactions are handled by listening to the PointerEvents? Can this be even made in such a way that the OS setting of the double click delay is respected?

Note 1: I still must be able to detect a normal click (by listening to `pointerdown` and `pointerup`) as well as a drag (by listening to `pointerdown`, `pointermove` and later `pointerup`)
Note 2: I'm using "pure" JavaScript and modern browsers, jQuery is no option.

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event

Comment: Sadly: no it doesn't. As my listeners to the `pointerdown` and `pointerup` are preventing it from being emitted.

Comment: I believe `click` and `dblclick` are the high level events, and mousedown/mouseup & pointerdown/pointerup are the low level events. The browser should be sending you both the low and high level events, and you can react to `dblclick`. My guess is that the tricky thing is figuring out whether to cancel (preventDefault) some of the events.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a runnable example of listening to *both* the low level pointer events for dragging *and* the high level click events. We'll get a `click` event when pressing the mouse button, moving the mouse, and releasing the button. But we probably want to treat that as a *drag*. So I have a variable `gotMoveEvent` to detect that there was a drag.

```js
// code based on https://www.redblobgames.com/making-of/draggable/

const messages = document.querySelector("figcaption");
const draggable = document.querySelector("circle");

let dragging = false;
let gotMoveEvent = false;

draggable.onpointerdown = (event) => {
   if (event.button !== 0) return; // only drag on left click
   draggable.classList.add("dragging"); // css feedback
   event.currentTarget.setPointerCapture(event.pointerId); // capture
   dragging = true;
   gotMoveEvent = false;
   messages.innerText = "Click or drag?";
}

draggable.onpointerup = (event) => {
   dragging = false;
   draggable.classList.remove("dragging"); // css feedback
}

draggable.onpointercancel = draggable.onpointerup;

draggable.onpointermove = (event) => {
   if (!dragging) return;
   gotMoveEvent = true;
   messages.innerText = "Dragging";
   let p = convertPixelToSvgCoord(event);
   draggable.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${p.x},${p.y})`);
}

draggable.onclick = (event) => {
   if (gotMoveEvent) {
      messages.innerText = "Ignoring click event because we were dragging";
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
   }
   messages.innerText = "Got click";
}

draggable.ondblclick = (event) => {
   // maybe: check for gotMoveEvent here too?
   messages.innerText = "Got dblclick";
}



/** Convert from event coordinate space (on the page) to SVG coordinate
 * space (within the svg, honoring responsive resizing, width/height,
 * and viewBox) */
function convertPixelToSvgCoord(event, relativeTo=event.currentTarget.ownerSVGElement) {
    // if relativeTo is the <svg> then its ownerSVGElement is null, so we want to point back to the <svg>
    // but otherwise we assume it's a child of <svg> and we want to find the <svg>
    let p = (relativeTo.ownerSVGElement ?? relativeTo).createSVGPoint();
    p.x = event.clientX;
    p.y = event.clientY;
    return p.matrixTransform(relativeTo.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}
```

```css
.draggable { fill: hsl(0 50% 50%); cursor: grab; }
.draggable.dragging { fill: hsl(200 50% 50%); cursor: grabbing; user-select: none; }
```

```html
<figure>
<figcaption>Drag or click</figcaption>
<svg viewBox="-200 -50 400 100" style="background:hsl(60 5% 95%)">
  <circle class="draggable" r="20" />
</svg>
</figure>
```

Comment: This works indeed with touch device